# .Net assemblies not working in PowerShell 2 runspaces

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I'm running powershell scripts from c# by way of `Runspace` and `Pipeline`.

I need to support Powershell 2

My script uses `[System.Net.WebRequest]`

From the PS CLI on this machine, `[System.Net.WebRequest]` works fine.

However, running a script from c# results in

```
Unable to find type [System.Net.WebRequest]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
```

I've tried using `Add-Type` to load `System.Net` and confirmed it is loaded with `[appdomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`

But the error persists

No issues if the computer has PS 3.0

**Edit:** Full relevant code

```
InitialSessionState initial = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initial);
runspace.ApartmentState = System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA;
runspace.Open();
using (Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline()) {
  pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);
  <invoke, read output etc>
}
```

Comment: Could be caused by running in MTA (default for PS 2). Make sure your runspace runs in Single Threaded Apartment (STA)

Comment: No luck. Confirmed with `[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.GetApartmentState()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a test app and found this to not be an issue.

The issue only occurs in my main app.

After a few hours of narrowing down the differences, I found that I could recreate the issue in my test app by loading and and using a shared module of mine.

I narrowed it down to a shared `GetMyVersion` routine in my shared DLL module.

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
return FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
```

The solution was to execute this code early within the exe. I was able to leave the regular usage of the shared DLL routine in the rest of the app.

Another solution that may be more reliable and also help in other circumstances is to directly access the assembly

```
$sysManagement = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Net");
$netType = $sysManagement.GetType("System.Net.WebRequest",$true);
$netType::Create("http://etc.com")
```